# AspNetCore.Mvc vs AspNetCore.Mvc.Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

What's the difference between the AspNetCore.Mvc and AspNetCore.Mvc.Core NuGet packages? Is Mvc.Core just bare bones stuff while Mvc is an all-inclusive package? That's what I would guess from looking at the descriptions [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) and [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/) but it's not totally clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4785

`AspNetCore.Mvc` has all the basic stuff already set for you

if you want to use `AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` you will have to configure them yourself

it seems wise to use `AspNetCore.Mvc` unless you KNOW you need `AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`

> - If you use `.AddMvc()` then you get a lot of "opinionated" features, e.g. what kind of app are you building, which formatters are registered and in what order, which application conventions are there by default.
> - If you use `.AddMvcCore()` ("and you know what you're doing) then the behavior of your application will be decided by your own opinions and not the built-in default opinions.